# How Can Use Dynamic Shadows In my unity AR project?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, shadow, lightning

I am trying to create a AR project to place furnitures by using camera. The shadows of the application do not change depending on the light. I need dynamic shadows that respond to light.

I used Shadow Receiver URP (AR)Shadow Receiver URP (AR) Asset for my APP , my shadows are static
how can i make them dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

You're after the Light Estimation feature This feature uses the camera's image feed to estimate the environmental lighting conditions in real-time.

To light your 3D AR models based on the real-world lighting using the Light Estimation feature, you can follow these steps:

- Enable Light Estimation on the AR Camera Manager script (found on the AR Camera) by checking the "Enable Light Estimation" option.
- Create a Directional Light object in your scene by right-clicking in
  the Hierarchy window, selecting "Light," and then choosing
  "Directional Light."
- Attach a "Light Estimation" script to the Directional Light object.
  This script will allow the Directional Light to update its settings
  based on the real-world lighting conditions detected by the AR
  camera. This is something you will have to write yourself; there are plenty of tutorials that can help you with this e.g. https://youtu.be/nw6-U_mSvQQ

With these steps, your 3D models will be lit based on the real-world lighting conditions detected by the AR camera! Their shadows should be update dynamically as the real-world lighting changes.

Hope this helps! Let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: Thank you for your help! But I tried the video you sent. It doesn't work correctly Do you have a sample script for light estimation that you can share with me ? Thank you again.

Comment: Could you give me more info on what you mean by "it doesn't work correctly"? That video is a essentially sample script, so I can always try and help you get it working if you let me know the issue.